# What does "over" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

We are specialized in packing, and I have a client Email to me as below:

> . . . do you over shrink-wrap service or is it included in the price?

He uses *over* here, what does he mean?

Answer (score 4):

This is a typo or misspelling of "offer" – nothing more or less.

Comment: Oh,yes, this makes sense. Thank you! +1

Comment: You know, you can actually give me +10 by clicking on the upward-pointing arrow next to my answer. and you should also be able to accept it if you think it is right.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry!

Comment: This answer might be correct; however, it's worth noting that, in packaging, there is _shrinkwrapping_, which is also known as [_overwrapping_](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=overwrap+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). Conceivably, then, the inquiry could be a carelessly worded question about whether overwrapping/shrinkwrapping will cost an additional fee, or if it's included in the quoted price. It's hard to tell for sure, with such a small excerpt provided in the O.P.'s question.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility which never occurred to me. Could be.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot know for sure, but *over* is statistically rather more likely to be a typo for ***cover*** that merely left off the *c-* than it is for *offer*, whose edit distance is much further away.

Comment: *Much* farther away? (1 vs 2 assuming [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).) Furthermore, does your probability model incorporate the keyboard layout (proximity of the letters v and f), or the pronunciation similarity? 

I like your answer because it offers a valid alternative, but my immediate thought was also that it was a typo for offer.

Comment: @iterums It really depends on how you weight your edit-actions. I agree that key proximity should matter, since we’re talking about fumblefinger likelihood here.

Comment: This could be a post-spell-checker typo: *offer* is easily mistyped as *ofer*, then the wrong correction is accepted giving *over*.

Comment: In the case of a human's fumble-fingered typo, I'd lean toward this theory: _cover_ - _c_ = _over_, with no resulting red squiggly line underneath. However, if it was a mistake made by speech recognition software, I might lean toward the other theory: ˈôfər ↝ˈōvər (or, if you'd prefer, ˈɑfər ↝ˈoʊvər), particularly if the speaker was talking fast and failing to enunciate clearly and carefully.